# Expert Witness in USA Divorce Trial

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I am a forensic accountant and have been helping a lot of US-based client in conducting divorce forensics. Is it possible for me to travel to the US on a B1/B2 visa to act as an expert witness? The work is done outside the US and I am just going there to present the findings to the court.

Comment: If you are an expert witness then you are presumably talking to lawyers. Lawyers will know more about this than we do - or at least know another lawyer who knows much more than we do. Ask them.